# speed up nested loops in R to create an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, parallel-processing, adjacency-matrix

I need some help parallelizing or speeding up the following nested loop:

1. have a list of vertices (identified by an id number), and each id has a string of numbers associated with it (the strings are of finite length, typically 60-200).

`id` is a list of approx. 10,000 distinct ids

`seq` is a list of (different length) sequences, each sequence associated with a unique id

2. I want to build the adjacency matrix for the graph on these vertices where vertex `i` and vertex `j` are connected if their sequences have common elements. Here is the code I am trying to improve:

   ```
   id_matrix<-matrix(nrow=length(id),ncol=length(id))
   for (i in 1:(length(id)){
      for (j in 1:(length(id)){
         edgelist[i,j]=length(intersect(seq[i],seq[j])
      }
   }
   ```

(This will produce 0 for non-overlapping id sequences, and a finite number whenever there is an overlap, which could be used as weights for the edges, and normalized).

I tried options like `foreach`, `dopar`, etc., but I have not been successful. Running with `length(id)=100` takes more than 2 minutes! A full run will take at least a month! I am working on a Windows PC with R Studio version 0.98.507.

Any help would be much appreciated, especially on parallelizing these two nested loops in R.

Note: this is a sparse matrix: about 1% of all possible 10^8 edges occur.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look into package igraph.

Comment: I agree that `igraph` (or maybe `Rcpp`) is probably the way to go. For interest, the base R solution might look something like this: `library(parallel); v <- setNames(replicate(10, sample(100, sample(5:10, 1))), 1:10); cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1); clusterExport(cl, 'v'); adj <- parSapply(cl, v, function(x) sapply(v, function(y) length(intersect(x, y)))); stopCluster(cl)`.

Comment: is `edgelist` initialized? A 10.000 x 10.000 loop should be doable in reasonable time.

Comment: After playing around with different options, it looks like the most speed gain (without any fancy parallelization) is the vectorizing of the sequences:

Comment: It looks like the most speed gain (without any parallelization) is the vectoriziation: seq<-vector(mode="list",length=10,000) then seq[[i]]<-(sequence of numbers), so the code changes "intersect(seq[[i]],seq[[j]])". For the 1000x1000 case, it took about a minute, which is an immense improvement over the previous attempts where a 100x100 matrix took more than 2 minutes. Once I have the adjacency matrix, I will use graph for the analytics. jbaums, thank you for the parallelized version of the algorithm, I will def need it for the larger networks (10^7 edges).

Comment: What was `seq` originally? Your post implied it was a list of vectors already (so it's not clear to me how `intersect(seq[i], seq[j])` would work anyway).

Answer (score 0):

On my computer

```
id_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = length(id), ncol = length(id))
for (i in 1:length(id)) {
    for (j in i:length(id)) {
        id_matrix[cbind(c(i,j),c(j, i))] <- length(intersect(seq[[i]],seq[[j]]))
    }
}
```

takes less than half an hour when `length(id)` is 10000.